# grep for same occurrence more than once

Tags: bash, grep, awk

Is it possible to grep or awk for more than 1 occurrence of the **same** string from a file?

```
awk '/$STRING|$STRING/' file

grep -e $STRING -e $STRING file
```

I tried other options but still not able to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not greps default behaviour? Do you mean n number of times?
The easiest way to day that I think is to have it print each match on a separate line

*-o, --only-matching*

and then pipe that to

*-m NUM, --max-count=NUM*

so it stops after a given number of lines (and thus matches)

cat test | grep test -o | grep test -m 1

Comment: No need to `grep` twice, piping the output of `grep -o` to `wc -l` would do it too. Also, superfluous call to `cat`.